# locating unused ports in python without binding them

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ports

Firstly i know that you can use the socket constructor with port = 0 to find an unused port, but this isn't my question.

I'm using a python script as an intermediate code between two applications, i want the python script to locate a free port for both applications so that they can communicate, i haven't found a graceful way to locate unused ports in python without binding them to a socket, is it possible without binding? or am i forced to do so?

This is a code that does so, by binding the port and closing it asap but i still don't feel that this is good practice

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('localhost',0))
addr,port = s.getsockname()
s.close()
print(addr)
print(port)
```

the connection is going to be temporary between the apps and many instances could occur

I'm literally looking for pointers on good practice of doing so, and i wanna know if what I'm doing is correct or I'm heading the wrong way

Comment: Why not bind and claim the unused port? If you don't, you incur the risk of another program using a port you've found but not yet bound to. This is a non-theoretical risk if you run multiple copies of your program at the same time. They could interfere with each other.

Comment: that is a risk that i'm afraid of, i'm actually passing that un-used port to a virtual machine so it can use a port on my server, so i'm trying to use python to assign ports to it

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The virtual machine's ports are separate from the host's ports, no?

Comment: well shortly, i'm trying to give it an exit port to actually interface with outside applications, like i'm actually exposing it to outside apps by mapping a port from my server to a certain port in it

Comment: why can't your `outside apps` choose a port for you ?

Comment: Because the app is inside a VM and I want to map a free port to be able to access the VM, as in I'll tell the VM this port is yours but with a python script